# Does there exist an AES 128 or 256 GCM implementation in pure JavaScript or C?

Tags: javascript, c, cryptography

I have been searching around for a pure JS implementation of AES 128 or 256 GCM but haven't found anything on GitHub. If none exist, perhaps there is one in Ruby or C in a minimal way for easy reading. Every language seems to only have a wrapper around OpenSSL to get this AES 128 or 256 GCM implementation, but I would like to see a simplified version for learning. Also, I can't even seem to find the [OpenSSL implementation](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/find/master).

[Forge](https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge/blob/master/lib/aesCipherSuites.js) doesn't seem to have it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a pure JS implementation of AES GCM On CyberChef.

https://gchq.github.io/CyberChef/#recipe=AES_Encrypt(%7B'option':'Hex','string':''%7D,%7B'option':'Hex','string':''%7D,'GCM','Raw','Hex')

They also support 128 bit.

This under the hood appears to use "node-forge"

https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge/blob/master/lib/aes.js

And the implementation is right there.

Comment: Where is the source code?

Comment: Oh awesome, thanks! Looks like [forge does potentially have it](https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge/blob/628b17fb5bc0bf22074b632432ffa535805a1b2b/lib/cipherModes.js#L509), though it appears difficult to read.